# React Hooks Clock - Clear SetInterval After Certain Time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

I have a stopwatch function in React that I would like to stop after 15 minutes. I am not sure how to use `clearInterval()` in this case:

```
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  const [isPaused, setIsPaused] = useState(false);
  const countRef = useRef(null);
  const lastUpdatedRef = useRef(null);
  const [minutes,setMinutes] = useState(0)
  const [seconds,setSeconds] = useState(0)


  const timeCeiling = 900; //maximum minutes is 15
  const timeFloor = 60; //maximum seconds is 60 so it resets after

  useEffect(() => {
    if (timer < timeCeiling) {
      setMinutes(Math.floor(timer / 60));
      setSeconds(timer % 60);
    } else {
      setMinutes(15);
      setSeconds(0);
    }
  }, [timer]);


  const handleStart = () => {
    setIsActive(true);
    setIsPaused(true);
    countRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTimer((timer) => timer + 1);
    }, 1000);
    lastUpdatedRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setLastUpdated(Date.now());
    }, 30000);
  };
```

The user clicks on the `handleStart` function which triggers a `useEffect`. It also has a `lastUpdated` dependency which triggers another function every 30 seconds.

The clock should end after 15:00 but it still continues after- where should I put `clearInterval` so that it stops the clock after 15 minutes? Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add cleare interval in the else condition:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (timer < timeCeiling) {
    setMinutes(Math.floor(timer / 60));
    setSeconds(timer % 60);
  } else {
    setMinutes(15);
    setSeconds(0);
    countRef.current && clearInterval(countRef.current);
    lastUpdatedRef.current && clearInterval(lastUpdatedRef.current);
  }
}, [timer]);
```

And you should cleare interval when component un-mount:

```
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    countRef.current && clearInterval(countRef.current);
  };
}, [countRef]);

useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    lastUpdatedRef.current && clearInterval(lastUpdatedRef.current);
  };
}, [lastUpdatedRef]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would place it in the `useEffect` that is running each time `timer` updates. Clear the interval in the else branch when the limit it hit.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (timer < timeCeiling) {
    setMinutes(Math.floor(timer / 60));
    setSeconds(timer % 60);
  } else {
    clearInterval(countRef.current);
    setMinutes(15);
    setSeconds(0);
  }
}, [timer]);
```

You might also want to add an additional `useEffect` hook to clear any running timers should the component unmount before you manually clear them.

```
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    clearInterval(countRef.current);
    clearInterval(lastUpdatedRef.current);
  };
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `clearInterval` in the else block in `useEffect`. Maybe this way:

```js
else {
  setMinutes(15);
  setSeconds(0);
  clearInterval(countRef.current) // I hope this works
}
```